# How to iterate through rows in sheet1 given cell value in sheet2 and replace row in sheet1 with row in sheet 2?

Tags: vba, replace

I have to find and replace rows in sheet 1 given matching cell value in the same column in sheet2. The column number is 4.

HELPPP!!!

This is what I have right now and I get an error on next x.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets(Sheet1)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(sheet2)

    With wb
    For i = 1 To ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim lookupvalue As String
        lookupvalue = ws2.Cells(i, 4).Value

        For x = 1 To ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim rng As range
            For Each rng In range("D:D")

            If InStr(1, rng.Value, "lookupvalue") > 0 Then
                rng.Delete
            End If
        Next x
exitloop:
Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What error you get on x ?

Comment: you missed `Next rng` before `Next x`. This should fix the error, but still, I highly doubt that this will get the code do what you want. The loop on x seems useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As A.S.H. said, the code needs a little improvement:

1) The two inner loops need to be combined.

2) The new inner loop should go from the bottom up, due to the fact that you are deleting the cell, This is probably why you have the second inner loop but that just adds time to the sub.

3) you are currently only deleting the one cell at a time, any data around it will remain.  This may be what you want and so I left it, but if you meant to delete the entire row then uncomment the line that does that.

4) when testing with the instr function the variable should not be in quotes, with the variable in quotes it will look for that specific word "lookupvalues" and not the value assigned to that variable.

5) The with block that was being used did nothing.  when using the with block the line that use it need to start with a '.' for example: on your code the with was with the workbook so every time a worksheet is used it should start with a "." like `.ws1...` and so forth.  But by declaring the sheets using the workbook, this is no longer needed.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lookupvalue As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("sheet2")


For i = 1 To ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    lookupvalue = ws2.Cells(i, 4).Value
     For x = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        Set rng = ws.Cells(x, 4)
        If InStr(1, rng.Value, lookupvalue) > 0 Then
            rng.Delete 'this only deletes the cell
            'You may want this instead
            'rng.entirerow.delete
        End If
    Next x
Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks all for quick replies and comments. Any idea as to why I am getting a Compile Error: Invalid Next control variable reference on rng?

Comment: @ichoi opps, sorry, changed the loop half way through and forgot to change the next.  I edited the code.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought you meant initially but if I make that change I get another error that says type mistmatch on Set ws = wb.Sheets(Sheet1)

Comment: @ichoi it was the way the sheets were named they need to be in quotes.

Comment: Sub DeleteRows()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As range
Dim lookupvalue As Variant

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")


For i = 1 To ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    lookupvalue = ws2.Cells(i, 4).Value
     For x = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        Set rng = ws1.Cells(x, 4)
        If rng = lookupvalue Then
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next x
Next i



End Sub

Comment: thanks for the help, it really helped a bunch. above is the final working code

Comment: @ichoi glad I could help, please consider marking as correct.

Comment: how do i do that? sorry new to the site

Comment: @ichoi there is a green check mark under the down arrow to top/ left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose an alternative way to handle this using a For Each Loop and the Find Method of the Range object.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim lookup_rng As Range
   Dim lookupvalue As String
   Dim search_rng As Range
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim match_rng As Range

   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

   Set lookup_rng = Application.Intersect(ws2.Range("D:D"), ws.UsedRange)
   Set search_rng = Application.Intersect(ws.Range("D:D"), ws2.UsedRange)

   For Each rng In lookup_rng.Cells
      lookupvalue = rng.Value
      With search_rng
         Set match_rng = .Find(lookupvalue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
         Do Until NoMoreMatches(match_rng)
            match_rng.Delete 'Or match_rng.EntireRow.Delete if you want to delete the entire row.
            Set match_rng = .FindPrevious
         Loop
      End With
   Next
End Sub

   Private Function NoMoreMatches(MatchRng As Range) As Boolean
      NoMoreMatches = MatchRng Is Nothing
   End Function
```

This approach is a little bit more wasteful then that of Scott Craner since the Find method always starts from the end of the range. However, I think it has the advantage that it is easier to read, i.e. that the code more directly shows what it is supposed to do.

Moreover, using this version you could extract the loops into a separate Sub you can use for arbitrary lookup and search ranges.